# R: How to recode multiple variables at once

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have several variables in my dataset that need to be recoded in exactly the same way, and several other variables that need to be recoded in a different way. I tried writing a function to help me with this, but I'm having trouble.

```
library(dplyr)
recode_liberalSupport = function(arg1){
  arg1 = recode(arg1, "1=-1;2=1;else=NA")
  return(arg1)
}

liberals = c(df$var1, df$var4, df$var8)
for(i in unique(liberals)){
  paste(df$liberals[i] <- sapply(liberals, FUN = recode_liberalSupport))
}
```

R studio works on this for about 5 minutes then gives me this error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, liberals, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 9 rows, data has 64600
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'liberals'. 
2: In df$liberals[i] <- sapply(liberals, FUN = recode_liberalSupport) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you

Comment: You probably want to use `mutate_at` instead of `apply`, here. I think your syntax for `recode` is also not correct. Providing sample data is the best way to get working answers

Comment: One issue is the your for loop.  `unique(liberals)` is going to have fewer values than `liberals`

Comment: Does this make sense `paste(df$liberals[i] <- sapply(liberals, FUN = recode_liberalSupport))`? (The issue is with `paste`.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is neater I think with **dplyr**. Using `recode` correctly is a good idea. `mutate_all()` can be used to operate on the whole dataframe, `mutate_at()` on just selected variables. There are lots of ways to specify variables in **dplyr**.

```
mydata <- data.frame(arg1=c(1,2,4,5),arg2=c(1,1,2,0),arg3=c(1,1,1,1))

mydata

  arg1 arg2 arg3
1    1    1    1
2    2    1    1
3    4    2    1
4    5    0    1

mydata <- mydata %>% 
     mutate_at(c("arg1","arg2"), funs(recode(., `1`=-1, `2`=1, .default = NaN)))

mydata

  arg1 arg2 arg3
1   -1   -1    1
2    1   -1    1
3  NaN    1    1
4  NaN  NaN    1
```

I use NaN instead of NA as it is numeric is be simpler to manage within a column of other numbers.

Comment: I see how this works, but how can I put the recoded variables in `mydata` back into my original dataframe?

Comment: @Steven Ok but doesn't this essentially recode all the variables in my data the same way? What if I want to recode some variables like `1=-1, 2=1, .default = NaN` and some like `1=1, 2=-1, .default = NaN`? Then put them all back into the same dataframe

Comment: Use `mutate_at(var1, var3, ...etc)`

Comment: Does `.default` mean "every other value not specified"?

Answer (score 0):

As always there are many ways of doing this. I don't know dplyr well enough to use that function, but this seems to be what you are looking for.

```
mydata <- data.frame(arg1=c(1,2,4,5),arg2=c(1,1,2,0))
mydata
  arg1 arg2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    4    2
4    5    0
```

Function to recode using a nested `ifelse()`

```
recode_liberalSupport <- function(var = "arg1", data=mydata) {
+   recoded <- ifelse(mydata[[var]] == 1, -1,
+                           ifelse(mydata[[var]] == 2, 1, NA))
+   return(recoded)
+ }
```

Call the function

```
recode_liberalSupport(var = "arg1")
[1] -1  1 NA NA
```

Replace the variable `arg1` with recoded values.

```
mydata$arg1 <- recode_liberalSupport(var = "arg1") 
mydata
  arg1 arg2
1   -1    1
2    1    1
3   NA    2
4   NA    0
```